# how to use ansible postgress query with dynamic args

Tags: sql, postgresql, ansible

I have some ansible role where I need to pass part of the db name dynamically, I can not get rid of sql file due to some limitation, so I tried below code but did not work

```
- name: Select query to my_test db with named_args
  postgresql_query:
    db: test_db
    path_to_script: myscript.sql 
    named_args:
      schema: mytest 
      table_pfix: test
```

myscript.sql file is

```
set SCHEMA %(schema)s; 
select  count(*) from my_%(table_pfix)s;
```

When I run this role,  I am getting syntax error

```
{"changed" : false, "msg": "can not execute sql schema 'set SCHEMA %(schema)s;\nslect  count(*) from my_%(table_pfix)s;'
{'scheam':mytest,'table_pfix':'test'}: synatax error at near \"'my_test'\" LINE 2 : slect count(*) from my_'test';
```